# How can I change the color in RegionPlot?

Tags: plotting, color

I need to graph $$y\geq \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$$
so, I'm using the function PlotRegion[condition,{var1,min,max},{var2,min,max}], so I obtained

```
PlotRegion[y>=1/(1+x^{2}), {x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}
```

But it generates a standard graph, with the region of the condition.

What I would like to know is how I can make the color intensity stronger as the region becomes stronger.
For example, if I go up on the $Y$ axis, I would like to know how to make the color become more intense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reply the comment**

```
RegionPlot[y >= 1/(1 + x^2), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Red}, #2] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image]

Like this?

```
RegionPlot[y >= 1/(1 + x^2), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, GrayLevel[1 - y]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

```
RegionPlot[y >= 1/(1 + x^2), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["PigeonTones"][1 - y]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can I do something similar, but not with the gray color, for example change gray color for light blue or red color?

Comment: @Ramanujan Yes, it can be done by using `Blend`,see the updated.

Comment: Wow! That's fantastic! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `Texture[LinearGradientImage[...]]` as the setting for `PlotStyle`:

```
RegionPlot[y >= 1/(1 + x^2), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[LinearGradientImage[{Bottom, Top} -> {White, Red}]]]
```

[image]

With 12.2 we can also use [`LinearGradientFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearGradientFilling.html)

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[y >= 1/(1 + x^2), {{x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}}], 
  PlotStyle -> LinearGradientFilling[{White, Red}, Top], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 150]
```

[image]